# Row visibility in CGridView in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I can't set row visibility to false. In CGridView i use option "visible" :

```
array(
            'type' => 'raw',
            'name' => 'Value',
            'value' => '$data->invc_confirmed_value',
            'visible' => '$data->invc_is_changed == 1'
)
```

But i think with this option i can't get value of my $data->invc_is_changed field. I have already tried '$data->invc_is_changed' == 1 variant and ('$data->invc_is_changed' == 1) but it doesnt work.

Comment: Do u want to hide the coloumn based on some value ??

Comment: Yes, I want to do that

Comment: $data->invc_is_changed == 1 what wer you trying to do ??

Comment: It is flag of changing my field. For example : I need to change some field in my table, but also I need to save started value. I put my new value into other field and mark my raw with field "is_changed" and then check status and if it changed i should set invisible my old field and set visible new field

Comment: See if invc_is_changed field is set with correct value in database then the below code provided should hide and show the column properly

Comment: Value is correct but visible parameter need only boolean value and i think expression in '' will be interpreted like plain text and always will have true value

Comment: Remember that the $data you have access is a row while you want to hide a column. What happen if column has 3 rows pass condition and 2 other rows does not? The decision to show or hide column depend on when you put the code to show column or not on your grid snippet code, not on column's data. The 'visible' is option for you to easily change it from other ambience variables which don't come from your grid at all

Comment: @TelvinNguyen, thank you for your answer and advice and sorry for wasting your time. I have found other solution of my problem. I just choose my values with condition in value property. e.g. 'value' => '$data->invc_is_changed ? $data->invc_changed_value : $data->invc_stated_value'